# Rails: Deploying a staging environment: Devise Secret Key was not set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cloud66

Right now, our company has a working production version of our company hosted on cloud66. I went through and set all of our environment variables and got our manifest up to snuff. Right now, aside from our API keys, staging is an exact replica of production. Our production.rb file is the same as sour staging.rb file:

```
#staging.rb
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Mailer
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    :port           => "587",
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => 'apikey',
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY'],
    :domain         => ENV['BASE_DOMAIN'],
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

  # Mailer for Devise
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: ENV['FULL_URL'] }

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "gathrly_#{Rails.env}"
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

I added the staging settings to our c66 manifest file, which again, is an exact copy of production:

```
# C66 manifest file
production:
    postgresql:
        configuration:
            version: 9.6.1
            postgis: false
staging:
    postgresql:
        configuration:
            version: 9.6.1
            postgis: false
```

Deployment failed and the logs are pointing to Devise:

```
#C66 deployment logs
[52.36.55.118] /var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/releases/20170311214608/config/database.yml
[52.36.55.118] done
* sftp upload complete
* executing `deploy:db:create'
* executing "cd /var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/releases/20170311214608 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=staging db:create"
[52.36.55.118] executing command
Database 'OurApp_staging' already exists
command finished in 2328ms
* executing `deploy:db:load_schema'
* executing "cd /var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/releases/20170311214608 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=staging db:schema:load"
[52.36.55.118] executing command
rake aborted!
Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializer:
config.secret_key = **REDACTED**
Please ensure you restarted your application after installing Devise or setting the key.
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:498:in `raise_no_secret_key'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:226:in `devise_for'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/releases/20170311214608/config/routes.rb:5:in `block in '
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:389:in `instance_exec'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:389:in `eval_block'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:371:in `draw'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/releases/20170311214608/config/routes.rb:1:in `'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_r
eloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:77:in `execute'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:119:in `block in '
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/releases/20170311214608/config/environment.rb:5:in `'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ru
by/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:448:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
command finished in 2584ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
* executing "rm -rf /var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/releases/20170311214608; true"
[52.36.55.118] executing command
command finished in 286ms
failed: ". /var/.cloud66_env 2>/dev/null || true && unset BUNDLE_GEMFILE && sh -c 'cd /var/deploy/OurApp/web_head/releases/20170311214608 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=**REDACTED** db:schema:load'" on 52.36.55.118
21:47:27 –  Deployment failed: Failed to setup the deployment on the server during "cap deploy"
```

So, I'm looking in the devise.rb file and I see this commented out code:

```
# The secret key used by Devise. Devise uses this key to generate
# random tokens. Changing this key will render invalid all existing
# confirmation, reset password and unlock tokens in the database.
# Devise will use the `secret_key_base` as its `secret_key`
# by default. You can change it below and use your own secret key.
# config.secret_key = 'somekey' # Real key removed for security.
```

I don't know much about this chunk of code. I would assume since everything is an exact replica of production that this should stay commented out for our staging environment as well. I don't know the implications of uncommenting out the `config.secret_key` and what that might do to our production environment.

Can someone explain why this works in production but is failing in staging which is identical in the rest of the settings?

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue. I forgot to add in staging information to `secrets.yml` where the secret_key_base is set.